# internet wont connect despite working wireless/ethernet

Tags: networking

I have 12.10 installed on a partitioned drive along with windows 7 on a new gateway pc. Ubuntu will not connect to the internet, while windows will. I have spent many many hours reading forums trying to fix this problem, but cannot figure it out. 
My wireless card is made by realtek. Its driver, rtl8192ce, appears to be working. I can scan for and pick up wireless networks. It says I am connected. I can ping 8.8.8.8 successfully. However: I cannot ping www.google.com or use a browser, install updates or anything of the kind. If i plug in an ethernet cable, or turn the wireless on and off it will sometimes get a connection for a few moments. I have tried blacklisting possible competing drivers, but as best as I can tell, only one is running. Overall I am an linux novice, everything I know about it comes from trying to solve this problem. Any help would be very very appreciated.

Comment: Check with your ISP, it sounds like something along the lines, such as the DNS servers, is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS issue.

Take a look at your dns settings here

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

//Append your ISP name server or free fast dns nameservers IP address as follows:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Or if you have played with bind9 check

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options:`

```
  [...]

    forwarders {
         1.2.3.4;
         5.6.7.8;
    };

    [...]
```